# SqlDependency is not working if table is updated

Tags: sqldependency

I am trying to show online friends of a user. For this I have created a column `OnlineStatus` in `UserInfo` table.I have created a hub which ,on start,calls a function and that function sends a Ajax request to server to get the list of online friends. If a friend of that user logs in, the OnlineStatus will be set to 1 otherwise 0.For a user to see his online friends in real time I am using SqlDependency if the OnlineStatus column is updated and SiganlR to call a function of hub which in turn calls a function of Client and that function in turn sends a Ajax request to server requesting the updated list of online users. Hub ,on start, working fine but if a user logs out and SqlDependency is not getting called. Please help me to fix it.
And here is the action:

```
Public JsonResult FindOnlineFriends(long UserId)
        {
            List<UserDetails> onlinefriends = new List<UserDetails>();
            using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand())
                {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    builder.Append("select [UserId],[DisplayPhoto],[Name] from [dbo].[UserInfo] as userself,(");
                    builder.Append("(select [PersonId2] from [dbo].[FriendsRelation] where  [PersonId1] like @UserId) union");
                    builder.Append("(select [PersonId1] from [FriendsRelation] where  [PersonId2] like @UserId)) as friends ");
                    builder.Append("where [userself].[UserId]=[PersonId2] and [OnlineStatus]=1");
                    cmd.CommandText = builder.ToString();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId",UserId);
                    cmd.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
                    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(onlineFriends_OnChange);
                    con.Open();
                    using(SqlDataReader rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if(rdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while(rdr.Read())
                            {
                                onlinefriends.Add(new UserDetails { UserId = Convert.ToInt64(rdr["UserId"]), Name = rdr["Name"].ToString(), DisplayPhoto = rdr["DisplayPhoto"].ToString() });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return  Json(onlinefriends,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        private void onlineFriends_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                SocialNetworkHub.SocialNetworkHub.ShowOnlineFriends();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will work just only for one user. When you call `SqlDependency.Start()` or `SqlDependency.Stop()` it drops all the subscriptions. However, for your task it is better to use an open source realization of `SqlDependency` - [`SqlDependencyEx`](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs), because with this component you can monitor the `UPDATE` changes of the `UserInfo` table independently. The code example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.